# HTML - left-align <ul> element

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am working on a classic ASP site, and an unorderd list on the right nav bar needed to be left-justified. By removing the `<ul></ul>` tags and simply leaving the list items, I was able to accomplish this. However, now the text for the first item, which is apparently too long for the table cell it is housed in, bleeds into the second line. Does anyone know, without using a `<ul>` tag, how to justify the text properly?

Here is a screen shot. I need to have the word 'application' align with the first word in each of the bulleted items.

[image]

Here is the HTML from this section:

```
<p><strong><span style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;, &quot;sans-serif&quot;; color:#0070B9'>Please contact our Product Specialists for assistance with:</span></strong></p>
    <li><span style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;, &quot;sans-serif&quot;; color:#666666'>Submitting your first application</li>
    <li><span style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;, &quot;sans-serif&quot;; color:#666666'>Marketing Materials</span></li>
    <li><span style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;, &quot;sans-serif&quot;; color:#666666'>Quoting tools</span></li>
<p><strong><span style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;, &quot;sans-serif&quot;; color:#0070B9'><br />
```

EDIT 
Here is a screen shot of the list with the `<ul>` tag.

[image]

Comment: A list item with no parent UL is invalid HTML.

Comment: Do you have a set width in whatever you are using to make it a block?  That would cause all the code inside it to be contained in that width unless you used an `overflow:visible` or something

Comment: This seems to work for me: http://cssdesk.com/RXdyU  I think you have some other style causing this effect

Comment: Sorry, posted the right screen shot, but wrong HTML.

Comment: You need to tag this as a CSS question.  I'm sure that there's some sort of CSS definition you could apply to your <li> items

Comment: This page does not use CSS. This isn't something I've created, it's a legacy app that needed some re-working and I was tasked with doing it since i'm the new guy. I'm pretty limited in what I can add to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put back the UL and reduce the margin with css.

```
ul.exampleList {
margin-left: ??px;
}
```

Example with your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/jYmpG/